# Sparkxx Enterprise Architect - Sequence Diagram. How do I write one message to multiple database tables

Tags: sequence-diagram, enterprise-architect

Am trying to add a message in a Sequence Diagram to select data from three tables. Currently I have 3 table objects in the diagram, how do I add the arrow to go to all three tables? Or can I group the tables as one object - how would I do this?

Also, should there be a return message from the database table objects?

Answer (score 1):

I would wonder why you'd need three "table objects".  You're using Sparx, which is an object-oriented modeling tool.  Shouldn't you be thinking about the objects those represent instead of tables?

If it's three separate table mappers, you need three separate "arrows", because they're three separate method calls, right?

As for the return value, you can choose to have one if the method returns something besides `void`.

Worry less about the UML and more about the problem you're trying to solve.

I'd also counsel you to forget about diagramming to the same level of detail as writing code.  You're trying to communicate an idea here, not produce an engineering drawing.  Diagram enough to get started and then write some code that you can actually execute and unit test.  Once that's working, reverse engineer it into Sparx if you want all the gory details.

Comment: I fully agree. I would add that db tables aren't suitable for sequences since they themselves don't get called or return data, the database engine does.